# Swing application can't display a gif background properly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, gif

So I'm trying to display a GIF background to my java app but the GIF doesn't seem to display properly
[That's the GIF](https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-cb57b068e5b5.gif) but when I'm displaying it in my app the pixels just fly everywhere and it looks nothing like the original GIF

Code:

```
public class PlayerPanel extends JPanel
{
    Player player ;
    Image img;
    boolean moveFlag=false;
    private HashMap<Character,Integer> keyMap=new HashMap<>();

    public PlayerPanel()
    {
        img = (new ImageIcon("assets\\space.gif")).getImage(); //background
        player = new Player(this);

        keyMap.put('w',0);
        keyMap.put('s',0);
        keyMap.put('a',0);
        keyMap.put('d',0);

        addKeyListener(new KA());
        setFocusable(true);
    }
}

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(img,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),null);
    }
```

Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame f=new JFrame("Asteroids Game");
        PlayerPanel playerPanel=new PlayerPanel();
        f.add(playerPanel);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(1024,700);
        f.setResizable(true);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setFocusable(false);
}
```

Comment: forgot to add paintComponent() thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a size issue and the image size was kinda small
anyway, I managed to fix the bug by resizing the image to a larger resolution

Comment: Add the image to a JLabel and the label will paint the gif at its actual size.